# how to exclude private methods from graphviz/doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, doxygen-wizard

I have doxygen/graphiz running just fine for my java code (via the wizard), but the setting `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO` seems to only relate to the documentation, not the graphing. When using `UML_LOOK = YES` it includes private methods.

Is there a way to create dot collaboration/class diagrams via graphviz but no include private methods as the diagrams are massive?

If I set `UML_LOOK = NO` it only produces basic class diagrams with the class name and the look isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible using UML_LOOK (or if it is, I have yet to find out how).

You could generate your own dot diagrams or use a slightly more powerful/adapted tool, like [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/). It's a lot more work on your part, but you'll obviously get what you want.